# Do I need to clean up after a Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => task?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code with the Appearing called when a page opens and the Disappearing called before the page exits. The concept of running things on the MainThread is not clear to me so I would like to know.

Is there any clean up needed for this or should I put something in place to ensure the task clears up completely and is not left hanging there on the MainThread?

```
    public void Appearing()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ShowCards().ContinueWith((arg) => { }));
    }

    public void Disappearing()
    {
        App.showCardsWhile = false;
    }

    public async Task ShowCards()
    {
        App.showCardsWhile = true;
        while (App.showCardsWhile)
        {
            App.DB.GetData();
            // Display the data
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of cleanup are you talking about? You do not allocate unmanaged resources neither run/manage something outside your app. Main thread i nothing but a usual thread, except the fact that your UI was born there.

The other more important question is that I see no reason why you mix up database querying with data rendering. It feels like a reason why you have to dispatch your method to the main thread.